# Trouble finding tab character in list objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in C#, winforms application.

I am reading from a text file where each row has fields divided by tabs:

I am putting each row in a list named `tic_string`. From here I am trying to search each list object, find the tabs, and put each field in its own array. So there will be an array for `column a`, `column b`, `column c` ... etc.

The problem is when I try to find the tabs in my list objects, it finds nothing.  Here is my code:

```
string[] tic_num = new string[row_counter];
string[] tic_title = new string[row_counter];
string[] tic_owner = new string[row_counter];
string[] tic_open_date = new string[row_counter];

int last_tab = 0;
int char_counter = 0;
int feild_counter = 1;
int feild_char_count = 1;
int current_row=0;
string temp_feild = "";
char temp_char;
char tab_char = '\t';
foreach (string tic_string_value in tic_string)
{
    temp_char = tic_string_value[char_counter];
    if (temp_char == tab_char)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("tab_found");

        if (feild_char_count == 1)
        {
            temp_feild = "";
        }
        else
        {
            temp_feild = tic_string_value.Substring(last_tab, feild_char_count);
        }
        last_tab = char_counter;
        feild_char_count = 0;

        switch (feild_counter)
        {
            case 1:
                tic_num[current_row] = temp_feild;
                break;
            case 2:
                tic_title[current_row] = temp_feild;
                break;
            case 3:
                tic_owner[current_row] = temp_feild;
                break;
            case 4:
                tic_open_date[current_row] = temp_feild;
                break;
        }
    }
    current_row++;
    feild_char_count++;
    char_counter++;
    if (feild_counter == 5)
        feild_counter = 1;
}
```

Comment: Your example file data is probably missing in the question.

Comment: And from your code, does not `char_counter` should be `0` at the beginning of the `foreach` loop, to start reading from the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be too complicated for such simple task. Do not parse each line char by char, just use helper functions like `String.Split` etc.:

```
foreach (string tic_string_value in tic_string)
{
    var parts = tic_string_value.Split(new [] { '\t' }, 
                                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    tic_num[current_row] = parts[0];
    tic_title[current_row] = parts[1];
    tic_owner[current_row] = parts[2];
    tic_open_date[current_row] = parts[3];
    current_row++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I deduce from the style of your code that you are probably familiar with C/C++ and are new to C#, because this code has a particularly "C++" flavour to it. It reminds me very much of my own C# code when I first made the jump myself.

I am glad that you described the problem you are trying to solve rather than simply posting the code and asking where to find the bug because I think you can actually solve your problem much more simply.

Considering the following code (this assumes that you're iterating over each of the rows outside this code, and I omit some of the declaring of variables that you had already specified):

```
int field_counter = 0;
foreach (var field in tic_string.Split('\t')) {
    switch (field_counter++) {
        case 0:
            tic_num[current_row] = field;
            break;
        case 1:
            tic_title[current_row] = field;
            break;
        case 2:
            tic_owner[current_row] = field;
            break;
        case 3:
            tic_open_date[current_row] = field;
            break;
    }
}
```

This leverages the succinctness of C# and removes quite a few lines of code, which is always good. The String.Split method will take care of most of the string splitting for you, so there's no need to do it all manually and keep track of characters.

Note: I kept your original naming of some of the field names, although generally it is preferable to use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) in C# code.

Now I notice from your original code that it's possible you don't have "rows" in your data in an actual sense (i.e. split by newline characters) but rather you may have the data entirely tab separated and are using the fact that you have a fixed number of columns per row to split up rows.

If this was the case, might I suggest the following code block could help you:

```
int i = 0;
        foreach (var group in tic_string.GroupBy(x => i++ % 4)) {
            int current_row = 0;
            foreach (var field in group) {
                switch (group.Key) {
                    case 0:
                        tic_num[current_row] = field;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tic_title[current_row] = field;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tic_owner[current_row] = field;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tic_open_date[current_row] = field;
                        break;
                }
                current_row++;
            }
        }
```

Now of course you may need to adapt these blocks to your code rather than use it verbatim. I hope that they at least demonstrate a different way of thinking about the problem. In particular, learning to use the various [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ) extension methods and LINQ queries will also be very helpful - they are part of what allows C# code to be so quick and easy to develop.

Best of luck in solving your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a list instead of 4 string arrays:

```
    public class ObjectToBeUsed
{
    public Person(int num, string title, string owner, string opendate)
    {
        this.Num = num;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Owner = owner;
        this.OpenDate = opendate;
    }

    private int _num;

    public int Num
    {
        get { return _num; }
        set { _num = value; }
    }


    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    private string _owner;

    public string Owner
    {
        get { return _owner; }
        set { _owner = value; }
    }

    private string _opendate;

    public string OpenDate
    {
        get { return _opendate; }
        set { _opendate = value; }
    }

}
```

This is the class which describes each row in your text file.

```
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");
        string currentLine = null;
        List<ObjectToBeUsed> peopleList = new List<ObjectToBeUsed>();

        while ((currentLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] tokens = Regex.Split(currentLine, @"\t");
            peopleList.Add(new ObjectToBeUsed(Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]), tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]));
        }
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but if you need any further explaining, go ahead.